# How to find all those Sellers from the table who had increase in sales in at least 3 months consecutively in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find all those Sellers from below table who had increase in sales in at least 3 months consecutively?

```
Record | Seller_id  | Months    | Sales_amount
0        121        Feb           100
1        121        Jan           87
2        121        Mar           95
3        121        May           105
4        121        Apr           100
5        321        Jan           100
6        321        Feb           87
7        321        Mar           95
8        321        Apr           105
9        321        May           110
10       597        Jan           100
11       597        Feb           105
12       597        Mar           95
13       597        Apr           100
14       597        May           110
```

Comment: Are you really storing your months as three letter abbreviations?

Comment: No they are full names actually. Wrote them in abbr. in hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH a
AS (SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES -- source data
            (0, 121, 'Feb', 100),
            (1, 121, 'Jan', 87),
            (2, 121, 'Mar', 95),
            (3, 121, 'May', 105),
            (4, 121, 'Apr', 100),
            (5, 321, 'Jan', 100),
            (6, 321, 'Feb', 87),
            (7, 321, 'Mar', 95),
            (8, 321, 'Apr', 105),
            (9, 321, 'May', 110),
            (10, 597, 'Jan', 100),
            (11, 597, 'Feb', 105),
            (12, 597, 'Mar', 95),
            (13, 597, 'Apr', 100),
            (14, 597, 'May', 110)
    ) t (id, Seller_id, Months, Sales_amount) ),
     b
AS (SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (1, 'Jan'),
            (2, 'Feb'),
            (3, 'Mar'),
            (4, 'Apr'),
            (5, 'May') -- , etc
    ) t (id, name) ),
     c
AS (SELECT a.*,
           b.id id2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Seller_id ORDER BY b.id ASC) rnk
    FROM a
        LEFT JOIN b
            ON a.Months = b.name),
     d
AS (SELECT --c1.*
        c1.Seller_id,
        c1.Months AS m1,
        c2.Months AS m2,
        c3.Months AS m3,
        c1.Sales_amount AS sa1,
        c2.Sales_amount AS sa2,
        c3.Sales_amount AS sa3
    FROM c c1
        LEFT JOIN c c2
            ON c1.id2 = c2.id2 - 1
               AND c1.Seller_id = c2.Seller_id
        LEFT JOIN c c3
            ON c2.id2 = c3.id2 - 1
               AND c2.Seller_id = c3.Seller_id)
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN sa1 < sa2
                AND sa2 < sa3 THEN
               1
           ELSE
               0
       END is_con
FROM d;
```

Comment: 121 Mar Apr May 95 100 105 1
321 Feb Mar Apr 87 95 105 1
321 Mar Apr May 95 105 110 1
597 Mar Apr May 95 100 110 1

Answer (score 2):

This is curious you have no year and months are three letter codes. Do it with lag
and table of months

```
With tbl as (
    select * from (values 
        -- source data
         (0 ,  121,'Feb',100)
        ,(1 ,  121,'Jan',87 )
        ,(2 ,  121,'Mar',95 )
        ,(3 ,  121,'May',105)
        ,(4 ,  121,'Apr',100)
        ,(5 ,  321,'Jan',100)
        ,(6 ,  321,'Feb',87 )
        ,(7 ,  321,'Mar',95 )
        ,(8 ,  321,'Apr',105)
        ,(9 ,  321,'May',110)
        ,(10,  597,'Jan',100)
        ,(11,  597,'Feb',105)
        ,(12,  597,'Mar',95 )
        ,(13,  597,'Apr',100)
        ,(14,  597,'May',110)
    ) t(id, Seller_id, Months, Sales_amount)
), months as (
     select * from ( values
         (1, 'Jan')
        ,(2, 'Feb')
        ,(3, 'Mar')
        ,(4, 'Apr')
        ,(5, 'May')
        -- , etc
      ) t(id,name)
)
select * 
from (
    select t.*,
       lag(Sales_amount,1) over (partition by Seller_id order by m.id) m1,
       lag(Sales_amount,2) over (partition by Seller_id order by m.id) m2
    from tbl t
    join months  m on m.name=t.Months
) t
where Sales_amount > m1 and m1 > m2;
```